# How can i show 10 images as a grid

Tags: subfloats, alignment

I have 10 images and I want them to display as a grid as shown in the figure. It should have a title and space at the end to describe the images in latex. I have kept the code I am already working on.

```
\begin{figure}[H]
% Global parameters for \includegraphics instructions:
\adjustboxset{height=0.18\textheight,width=0.18\textheight,valign=c}

\caption{Comparative analysis on our experiments with I66 Image} % provide a suitable caption

\begin{tblr}{colspec={c cc  cc}, colsep=4pt, rowsep=1pt,
             vline{4}={0em,white},
              }
BM3D        & I66                & DIP 
        & DIP TV                & Proposed            \\
\adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-.png} & \adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-.png} 
        & \adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-DIP.png} 
        & \adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-DIP_TV.png} 
        & \adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-best.png} \\
        
\adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-.png} & \adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-resid.png} 
        & \adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-DIP_noisy.png} 
        & \adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-DIP_TV_noisy.png} 
        & \adjustimage{}{fold1/I66-best_noisy.png} \\

\end{tblr}
\end{figure}
```

[image]

Comment: Search for `\subfloat` or `subfigure`. Here on site is buch similar questions with good answers. Your question hasn't any common with overleaf ;-)

Comment: I am previously not using sub floats. you can see from the sample code I have kept. I was hoping to modify the code to place 5 figures in  a row and alphabets for naming the images @Zarko

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked your code (it is very familiar to me). Just insert images in some table ... I can show possible solution late afternoon/evening (GMT)